# Passing parameters to SSPRS Report through the URL doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, parameter-passing, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to access a SSPRS report that has the option to select the year and the month by adding the parameters in the URL as &param=value but I always get the default.

This are the parameters and I know I'm sending the correct values in the URL.

[image: Parameters]

This is the report panel where I can select the Year and Month, I'm trying to get the specific report that I need by passing those parameters in the URL.

[image]

What could I be doing wrong?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: It would not hurt if you also specify a parametrized URL by you are trying to get the report rendered

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways these go wrong, I'm guessing your problem is URL encoding of your date parameter, but I'll give you other stuff too. Here is a working URL with 3 parameters: a date, a string, and an integer.

https://db01.MyCompany.com/ReportServer_Prod?/Reports/R440_OutstandingRecp&paramDateEnd=12%2f31%2f2015&paramPropLiab=Property&paramRepPeriod=1

The key parts of this URL: 
"https://db01.MyCompany.com/ReportServer_Prod?/" - db01.MyCompany.com is our database VM, and I'm using the "Prod" (production) instance of SQL on it. 
NOTE: Check your Reporting Services Configuration application and look at the "Web Service URL" to get what "ReportServer_Prod" is on your installation.

"?/Reports/" is the path to the virtual directory, note that this is different from the path a browser would normally use. Normally my path would be "ReportServer_Prod/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReports%2fR440_OutstandingRecp" if I was just viewing this from the Reporting Services interface.

Parameters are separated by "&" and it's "ParamName" "=" "ParamValue" so "&paramPropLiab=Property&paramRepPeriod=1" are the string and integer parameters respectively.

Lastly, parameter values are URL encoded if necessary. Mostly it doesn't show up, but for dates and some strings, it becomes necessary. We can't send something like "12/31/2015" because it looks like part of the path, we need a URL encoded string like "12%2f31%2f2015"

Hopefully one (or more) of these were what you needed, reply in the comments if it's still not working or if you need more explanation of why the parts are what they are.

EDIT: One more thing, if a parameter has a "Display" and a "Value" (i.e. in a drop down list) you must pass the value, not the display.

EDIT: I can't make the comment stop hiding my URL, so I'll put it here

WHAT WAS TRIED
   https://slo2000/Reports_TECOVA?/Reports/TEXO%20CVA%20Reports%2fTEXO_London_B_CVA_Report&ReportMonth=January&ReportYear=2020

https://slo2000/Reports_TECOVA?/Reports/TEXO%20CVA%20Reports/TEXO_London_B_CVA_Report&ReportMonth=January&ReportYear=2020

https://slo2000/ReportServer_TECOVA?/Reports/TEXO+CVA+Reports/TEXO_London_B_CVA_Report&ReportMonth=January&ReportYear=2020

WHAT WORKS (From @Nacho in comments, brought here for visibility)

http://slo2000/ReportServer_TECOVA/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2TEXO+CVA+Reports%2fTEXO_London_B_CVA_Report&rs:Command=Render&ReportMonth=January&ReportYear=2020

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help. I'm still not able to make it work. When I open the report through chrome, the url looks like this: `http://slo2000/Reports_TECOVA/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fTEXO+CVA+Reports%2fTEXO_London_B_CVA_Report`

Comment: then I tried the following urls but I always get the default values for the Year and Month: `http://slo2000/Reports_TECOVA/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fTEXO+CVA+Reports%2fTEXO_London_B_CVA_Report&ReportMonth=January&ReportYear=2020`

Comment: `http://slo2000/Reports_TECOVA/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fTEXO+CVA+Reports%2fTEXO_London_B_CVA_Report&rs:Command=Render&ReportMonth=January&ReportYear=2020`

Comment: Finally, if I try using the url as `http://slo2000/ReportsServer_TECOVA/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fTEXO+CVA+Reports%2fTEXO_London_B_CVA_Report` I get 404

Comment: Try "https://slo2000/Reports_TECOVA?/Reports/TEXO%20CVA%20Reports%2fTEXO_London_B_CVA_Report&ReportMonth=January&ReportYear=2020" Ugh, this keeps converting to a link, I'll modify the answer and use CODE tags

Comment: That link takes me to the 'root folder', so to speak.

Comment: OK, I modified my development reporting services to test, try the 3rd link I put in the answer, I still can't figure out how to keep comments from hiding mu URL. Also check your Reporting Services configuration "Web Service URL" and tell me what that is, it might be where we have problems.

Comment: With the last link I get `The item 'foo' cannot be found. (rsItemNotFound)`. About checking the Reporting Services configuration, I have no idea how to do it (lol), I didn't setup it, I'm just writing a script to fetch data from it.

Comment: I found out how to do it (it was just luck) `http://slo2000/ReportServer_TECOVA/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2TEXO+CVA+Reports%2fTEXO_London_B_CVA_Report&rs:Command=Render&ReportMonth=January&ReportYear=2020`. Thank you very much for your help.